# $\delta \in H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $s>\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, dirac-delta, dual-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

We know that the following definition for Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{ v \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n): (1+\xi^2)^{s/2} \hat{v}(\xi) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$, valid for $s\geq0$.

In these notes ([https://www.math.uci.edu/~chenlong/226/Ch1Space%20(Long-Chens-MacBook-Air.local's%20conflicted%20copy%202017-10-23).pdf](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Echenlong/226/Ch1Space%20(Long-Chens-MacBook-Air.local%27s%20conflicted%20copy%202017-10-23).pdf)), at example 1.11, the author says that $\delta \in H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $s>\frac{n}{2}$, and to justify this he basically put the Fourier transform of $\delta$, which is $1$, in the definition of the norm:

$$\int_{\Omega} (1+|\xi|^2)^s d\xi$$ and after integration in polars we have: $\delta \in H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $s>\frac{n}{2}$. However, **I don't see why this implies that $\delta$ is an element of the dual space**.

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems silly at first, but take $u\in H^s$ for $s>n/2$, and then pair it with $g\in H^{-s}$.

Comment: @Jose27 I'm sorry, but what do you mean with "pair it"?

Comment: @Jose27 Sorry for asking again, but could you be more precise? I still can't understand why that implies that $\delta$ is not in the dual

Comment: My comment used implicitly that you already had $H^{-s}"=" (H^s)^*$, with the identification given by the pairing $$\langle u, v\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \hat{u}(\xi)\hat{v}(\xi)\, d\xi,$$ for $u\in H^s$ and $v\in H^{-s}$.
^